# How do I redirect all requests unless an object is found in amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3

I want to redirect all requests unless an object is found in amazon AWS s3.  For example, say I have one file in my bucket called "index.html" and that bucket goes to example.com.  If I go to example.com/index.html I want to see that index.html page on example.com, but if I go to example.com/anything-else/ it brings me to 2.example.com/anything-else/. I know you can redirect all requests in s3, but I do not know how to do it like this.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `KeyPrefixEquals` will useful in your case

Please refer to Example #1 from the [AWS document this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html)

Comment: thanks!  I got this code: <RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>403</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>
      <HostName>www.unrealcousinzzz.net</HostName>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>